# How to do "tail this file until that process stops" in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a couple of scripts to control some applications (start/stop/list/etc). Currently my "stop" script just sends an interrupt signal to an application, but I'd like to have more feedback about what application does when it is shutting down. Ideally, I'd like to start tailing its log, then send an interrupt signal and then keep tailing that log until the application stops.

How to do this with a shell script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For just tailing a log file until a certain process stops (using `tail` from *GNU coreutils*):

```
do_something > logfile &
tail --pid $! -f logfile
```

**UPDATE** The above contains a race condition: In case `do_something` spews many lines into `logfile`, the `tail` will skip all of them but the last few. To avoid that and always have `tail` print the complete logfile, add a `-n +1` parameter to the `tail` call (that is even POSIX `tail(1)`):

```
do_something > logfile &
tail --pid $! -n +1 -f logfile
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know of the `--pid` flag!

Comment: Well, e.g. POSIX `tail` or busybox `tail` do not have the `--pid` flag, so you cannot widely rely on it actually being present.

Comment: I see, but GNU coreutils is "widely" enough for me ;-)

Comment: sadly, that means vanilla MacOS is out.  .... unless you unstall coreutils, which most people (other than me) done't

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Bash script that works without `--pid`. Change `$log_file` and `$p_name` to suit your need:

```
#!/bin/bash

log_file="/var/log/messages"
p_name="firefox"

tail -n10 $log_file
curr_line="$(tail -n1 $log_file)"
last_line="$(tail -n1 $log_file)"

while [ $(ps aux | grep $p_name | grep -v grep | wc -l) -gt 0 ] 
do
        curr_line="$(tail -n1 $log_file)"
        if [ "$curr_line" != "$last_line" ]
        then
                echo $curr_line
                last_line=$curr_line
        fi  
done
echo "[*] $p_name exited !!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to tail log until process exited, but **watch stdout / sdterr at the same time**, try this:

```
# Run some process in bg (background):
some_process & 
# Get process id:
pid=$!
# Tail the log once it is created, but watch process stdout/stderr at the same time:
tail --pid=$pid -f --retry log_file_path & 
# Since tail is running in bg also - wait until the process has completed:
tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```